# Mysql Result, array to json but adding an element

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this very beginner's skill code to get some info from a mysql database:

```
    var sql_select = "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1"
     connection.query(sql_select, Id, (error, results) => {
    if (error){
        return console.error(error.message);
    }
    console.log("result:", results);
});
```

I know how to get results from SQL select into JSON and get something like :

```
[{"COL1": "VALUE_COL_1", "COL2": "VALUE_COL_2"}]
```

but how can i get something like this instead?

```
[{"2020-01-01":{"COL1": "VALUE_COL_1", "COL2": "VALUE_COL_2"}]
```

(2020-01-01 would be a variable date set upper in the code).

Thanks

Comment: `["2020-01-01":{"COL1": "VALUE_COL_1", "COL2": "VALUE_COL_2"}]` is not valid. Do you mean `{{"2020-01-01":{"COL1": "VALUE_COL_1", "COL2": "VALUE_COL_2"}}` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), and using the [bracket form of the property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to set an property in an object.

```
 const output = []                           // empty new array
 results.forEach ( row => {
    const x = {}                             // empty object
    x[theDateStringFromSomeplaceElse] = row  // your row as value, date as name
    output.push( x )                         // push into the output array
 } )
 // now output has the array you want.
```